# Push a button and then wait for another button

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to make a Blackjack helping application in MIT App Inventor. I want the user to select the 2 cards that he has by clicking one button that maps to a card value and then click another one (could be the same button) and then take that input of 2 cards along with an input of 1 dealer card for processing. How can I click a button and then have it wait for another button to be pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `counter` variable
after clicking a button, add 1 to the counter
after clicking again, add again 1 to the counter
and only `if counter = 2`, then continue with your logic